# Using STL within the Mac 10.5 SDK

Tags: xcode, stl, artoolkit

Hopefully this is more relevant to StackOverflow than mac.stackexchange...

I am using ARToolkit for an augmented reality project, and in order to make it work under Mac I need to run the 10.5 SDK.

My problem is that I cannot seem to include any of the STL header files...especially vector.

Is there any sort of wrapper or workaround that I can use?  I am basically compiling straight C code, and would like to make use of some of the nicer features of the STL framework to speed up development...

---

Edit:

In closer inspection, it appears that ARToolkit is including std_vector at some point in its include path.

Error snippet:

```
Bits/c++allocator.h: No such file or directory
Expected template-name before '<' token
Expected `{' before '<' token
Expected unqualified-id before '<' token
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/iosfwd
Bits/c++locale.h: No such file or directory
Bits/c++io.h: No such file or directory
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_algobase.h
Bits/c++config.h: No such file or directory
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_vector.h
Expected type-specifier before 'allocator'
Expected '>' before 'allocator'
'input_iterator_tag' has not been declared
'forward_iterator_tag' has not been declared
'input_iterator_tag' has not been declared
'forward_iterator_tag' has not been declared
'input_iterator_tag' has not been declared
'forward_iterator_tag' has not been declared
There are no arguments to '__N' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of '__N' must be available
(if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
Expected nested-name-specifier before 'iterator_traits'
Expected initializer before '<' token
There are no arguments to '_IterCategory' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of '_IterCategory' must be available
Expected nested-name-specifier before 'iterator_traits'
Expected initializer before '<' token
There are no arguments to '_IterCategory' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of '_IterCategory' must be available
Expected nested-name-specifier before 'iterator_traits'
Expected initializer before '<' token
There are no arguments to '_IterCategory' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of '_IterCategory' must be available
/Users/espais/research/artoolkit/trunk/artoolkit/examples/newproject/newproject.cpp
Expected `}' at end of input
/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1/bits/stl_bvector.h
Expected template-name before '<' token
Expected `{' before '<' token
Expected unqualified-id before '<' token
```

Comment: Why can't you include the STL header files? What happens when you do?

Comment: The STL is a part of the C++ standard library. If what you're compiling is "basically straight C code", perhaps that might be your problem? ;)

Comment: True...I had hoped I could somehow switch the compiler to C++ (currently only options are LLVM GCC 4.2 and Apple LLVM compiler 3.0).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Including STL in source where a header already calls it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9949939/including-stl-in-source-where-a-header-already-calls-it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, there was some trickery that had to be done behind the scenes.
I had to update my local SDK (turns out that ARToolkit does support newer versions, regardless of what THEIR documentation says), and then the STL libraries worked.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to make your file a `.mm` file (Objective-C++) instead of `.m` (Objective-C).

Other than that, there shouldn't be any trouble doing `#include <vector>`.

Comment: Its actually a .C file.  I had hoped that I could switch the compiler to C++, but all I see is gcc in the list.

Comment: You can go into the project build settings and under GCC 4.2 Language section, select 'C++' under 'Compile Sources As' instead of 'According to File Type'.

Comment: Well, try renaming to `whatever.cpp` and see if that helps.

Comment: Done...seems to actually be an inclusion of stl_vector from ARtoolkit somewhere...